# Quirks mode only for IE versions below IE8

Tags: html

How do you activate quirks mode only for IE versions below IE8 on a page where the doctype html5 is set? Or, is possible to interpret a piece of code in quirks mode?

Comment: Do you want quirks mode for IE8 and below, or less than IE8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be possible to achieve this by combining any HTML comment (`<!-- anything -->`) before the doctype (this triggers Quirks mode in IE6—9) and `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"content="IE=Edge">` (which has precedence over the doctype and triggers Standards mode in IE8—9). So only IE6—7 will have Quirks mode, and IE8+ and all non-IE browsers will switch to Standards mode.

Comment: Any examples? I added <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"content="IE=Edge"> before <!doctype html> but with IE7 the display mode has been "Standard mode IE6".

Comment: No, you need to add `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"content="IE=Edge">` just after `<head>`. Before `<!DOCTYPE html>` there must be a html comment, like `<!-- old IE fix -->` or just `<!-- . -->`. See this example: http://selenit.freeoda.com/IE9/test.html

Comment: Ok, the test result in JavaScript on my page is "CSS1Compat" but display mode "Standard mode IE6". I noticed that by removing the doctype the page becomes "Quircks IE5 mode", which is what I want. How do I resolve?

Comment: Do you use something like IETester that reports this 'Standard mode IE6'? I tested this page on netrenderer.com, it reports 'BackCompat' (actually meaning IE5 Quirks mode) for IE6 and 'CSS1Compat' (meaning the latest Standard mode that's accessible) for IE8 and above. For IE7 it currently reports 'Internal Error XX' for some reason, but previously it reported 'BackCompat' exactly as for IE6.